# How to create an oAuth unique token for back-end connection

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I made a FastAPI API that is used by some other back-end and not directly by a front-end. I'm trying to add a security layer with oAuth but all I'd need is a unique access token that this other API would use every time it wanted to consume mine. I haven't seen anything like this on the documentation and I was wandering if this is possible without having to define a user-login model.

Comment: If you can pre-exchange the token (i.e. generate a long-ish random value), the implementation would be to just compare the supplied token (as shown in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/ ) to the pre-exchange value that you can add in an .env file or part of the application's configuration. Instead of looking up at user, you'd raise an httpexception with status code 403 if the token value differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that instead of using any oAuth library I would just implement this solution myself by adding a function to every endpoint I wanted to secure that requires a pre made unique token. By using hashlib library I can choose any hashing algorithm I want to check if the hashed string matches the defined token so the actual password doesn't live in the code.